# R data.table sum number of columns exceeding threshold

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization, threshold

I would like to sum the number of columns whose values exceed a threshold in an observation. Additionally, I would like to specify those column names and thresholds as vectors (`cols`, `th`)

Take the example data set:

```
x <- data.table(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c(3,2,1))
```

The goal is to create a new column `exceed.count` with number of columns in which x1 and x2 exceed a respective threshold.  Assuming the case in which the thresholds for both x1 and x2 are 2:

```
th <- c(2,2)
```

The function could be defined as:

```
fn <- function(z,th) (sum(z[,x1]>th[1],z[,x2]>th[2]))
```

And the number of columns exceeding the thresholds calculated by:

```
x[,exceed.count:=fn(.SD,th),by=seq_len(nrow(x))]
```

The results are:

```
   x1 x2 exceed.count
1:  1  3            1
2:  2  2            0
3:  3  1            1
```

What I would like to do is be able to specify the column names as vector, e.g.

```
cols <- c("x1","x2")
```

I was playing around with a function of the form:

```
fn.i <- function(z,i) (sum(z[,cols[i],with=FALSE] > th[i]))
```

which works for a single i, but how do I vectorize this across elements of cols? (`cols` and `th` will always be the same length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an easier way to solve your problem:

```
x<-data.table(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c(3,2,1))
th<-c(2,2)
x[,exceed.count:=sum(.SD>th),by=seq_len(nrow(x))]
```

Or, taking into account your input (only a subset of columns):

```
x<-data.table(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c(3,2,1))
sd.cols = c("x1")
th<-c(2)
x[,exceed.count:=sum(.SD>th),by=seq_len(nrow(x)), .SDcols=sd.cols]
```

Or

```
x<-data.table(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c(3,2,1))
sd.cols = c("x1")
th<-c(2,2)
x[,exceed.count:=sum(.SD>th[1]),by=seq_len(nrow(x)), .SDcols=sd.cols]
```

Comment: I should have been more specific that the columns I am comparing could only be a subset of the columns of x.  Your solution assumes all columns are included.  However, that does give me the idea to subset x into the columns I wish to compare and then merge the result back onto x.

Comment: I tried to include your input in my answer, if it helps you

Comment: If `ncol(x) != length(th)`, vector recycling will mess this up.

Comment: That is very true, Sir. I thought about naming `th` values so I could filter only those which are in `sd.cols` and create a `assert alert` in order of weird results, but I thought I was overcomplicating the issue. Thank you anyway for raising the issue.

Comment: Specifying a subset of columns with `.SDcols=sd.cols` is more performant. But you could get the same effect by just using all columns, don't specify `.SDcols`, and set the don't-care value `+Inf` in those columns of the threshold you don't want counted.

Answer (score 1):

@JonnyCrunch's approach, specifying a subset of columns with `.SDcols=sd.cols` works fine (as long as you ensure `ncol(x) == length(th)`, otherwise vector recycling will mess things up).

Here's an alternative that is shorter syntax (but will be less performant for very wide columns):

- `x[,exceed.count:=sum(.SD>th), by=seq_len(nrow(x)) ]`

  - no need to explicitly specify `.SDcols`, let it default to all columns
  - define the threshold vector `th` for all columns, using the don't-care value `+Inf` in those columns you don't want counted.

.

```
> x <- data.table(x0=4:6, x1=1:3, x2=3:1, x3=7:5)

   x0 x1 x2 x3
1:  4  1  3  7
2:  5  2  2  6
3:  6  3  1  5

> th <- c(+Inf, 2, +Inf, 2) 

> fn <- function(z,th) (z>th)

> x[,exceed.count:=sum(.SD>th), by=seq_len(nrow(x)) ]

   x0 x1 x2 x3 exceed.count
1:  4  1  3  7            1
2:  5  2  2  6            1
3:  6  3  1  5            2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get around iteration over rows:

```
x <- data.table(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(3,2,1))
thL <- list(x1 = 2, x2 = 2)

nm = names(thL)
x[, n := 0L]
for (i in seq_along(thL)) x[thL[i], on=sprintf("%s>%s", nm[i], nm[i]), n := n + 1L][]

   x1 x2 n
1:  1  3 1
2:  2  2 0
3:  3  1 1
```